# Condition to filter out records if no rows are found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple code

```sql
SELECT @Setting =(CASE
                    WHEN @capName = 'role1'
                        AND .....?  
                        THEN 1
                    ......                    --More than 1 case
                    ELSE 0
                  END)
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.accountId = 'nameA'
AND t.capName IN ('role1','role2')
```

I want to have a condtion of column **capName** here so that when table1 is **having no rows**, the @Setting will return 1.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe COALESCE is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT @Setting = COALESCE((CASE
                WHEN @capName = 'role1'
                    AND .....?  
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
              END), 1)
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.accountId = 'nameA'
AND t.capName IN ('role1','role2')
```

Comment: Can we do it inside WHEN clause? Because I have more than 1 case... This is just an example.

Comment: This is only works when there is only 1 case, but I have more than 1....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-- Default when no relevant rows exist
SET @Setting = 1; 
-- Try change it if any row exists
SELECT @Setting =(CASE
                    WHEN @capName = 'role1'
                        AND .....?  
                        THEN 1
                    ......                    --More than 1 case
                    ELSE 0
                  END)
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.accountId = 'nameA'
AND t.capName IN ('role1','role2')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you have multiple cases so please check out this code if this helps you.
set @Setting to 1 by default if there is no row then by default you are getting 1 otherwise your cases does the trick.

```
declare @capName varchar(10) = 'role1',
@Setting int = 1
select @Setting = (CASE
                WHEN @capName = 'role1' 
                    THEN 1
                    WHEN @capName = 'role2' 
                    THEN 2
                    WHEN @capName = 'role3' 
                    THEN 3
                ELSE 0
              END)
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.accountId = 'nameA'
AND t.capName IN ('role1','role2')
SELECT @Setting as [setting]
```